# What is the difference between tags random and prng?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently [random](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) has quite a vague tag wiki: "Governed by or involving equal chances for each item." [prng](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prng) doesn't have tag wiki at all.

When should tags [prng](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prng) and [random](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) be used?

Answer (score 1):

I feel a bit cautious about using the word PRNG, since it is not always used the same way by everyone.

- Sometimes it is used to refer to the thing that you use to generate entropy for a random seed or a random crypto key (think: `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom`).
- Other times, it is used to refer to a crypto algorithm that accepts a short seed/key and produces a long sequence of pseudorandom output (think: RC4, AES-CTR).
- Still other times, it is used to refer to a non-cryptographic algorithm for pseudorandom numbers (think: `rand()`).

This means there is some opportunity for ambiguity in what [prng](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prng) refers to.  Personally, I'm not sure we want to take a stance on this terminological question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

PRNG should be used specifically when talking about PRNG, whereas Random can apply to any random source.

You can always edit in the tag wiki if you like :-)